# Is this a bug in GNAT that I should report

Tags: ada, gnat

When I define my own type with a range that ends on 127, the compiler does not do upper bounds checking which allows the variable to wrap around and become negative below its defined limit. If I define the range as 126 then the proper exception is thrown. I included the programs and their output below.

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure GoodType is

    type GOOD_TYPE is range -1..126;

    package GOOD_TYPE_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(GOOD_TYPE);
    use GOOD_TYPE_IO;

    On_Both1 : GOOD_TYPE := 120;    
    Index : INTEGER := 0;

begin
    for Index in 120..130 loop
        On_Both1 := On_Both1 + 1;

        Put(Index);
        Put(": ");
        Put(On_Both1);
        New_line;        
    end loop;

end GoodType;
```

Output:

```
gnatmake -f goodtype.adb && ./goodtype
        120:  121
        121:  122
        122:  123
        123:  124
        124:  125
        125:  126

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : goodtype.adb:16 range check failed
```

.

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure BadType is

    type BAD_TYPE is range -1..127;

    package BAD_TYPE_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(BAD_TYPE);
    use BAD_TYPE_IO;

    On_Both1 : BAD_TYPE := 120;    
    Index : INTEGER := 0;

begin
    for Index in 120..130 loop
        On_Both1 := On_Both1 + 1;

        Put(Index);
        Put(": ");
        Put(On_Both1);
        New_line;        
    end loop;

end BadType;
```

Output:

```
gnatmake -f badtype.adb && ./badtype
        120:  121
        121:  122
        122:  123
        123:  124
        124:  125
        125:  126
        126:  127
        127: -128
        128: -127
        129: -126
        130: -125
```

Comment: Interesting that `badtype` carries on producing out-of-range values. I guess the logic is something like “we’re adding 1, so check that the result is still less than the upper bound”. Also interesting that if you add or subtract a variable the error is detected sooner even without `-gnato`; and when I compiled the program with the new GCC 4.9.0 and `-O2` it said `warning: iteration 2 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]` on the `On_Both1 := On_Both1 + 1;` line and entered a continuous loop when run.

Answer (score 6):

GNAT currently disables overflow checking by default (though [this behavior will change](http://www.adacore.com/developers/development-log/NF-73-L620-002-gnat/) in future releases).

Try:

```
gnatmake -gnato -f badtype.adb && ./badtype
```

The difference in behavior between `126` and `127` is apparently because the former is implemented as a range check (which is enabled by default), and the latter is implemented as an overflow check (which is disabled by default). You can see this in the differing error messages printed in the two cases (when compiled with `-gnato`:

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : goodtype.adb:16 range check failed
```

vs.

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : badtype.adb:16 overflow check failed
```

Comment: Why does it do the overflow checking in `goodtype`, though? That's inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's inconsistent. As I wrote in my answer, it's a matter of how the check is implemented. An overflow in `Good_Type` (upper bound 126) has to be checked by an explicit comparison in the generated code, which is done by default. An overflow in `Bad_Type` (upper bound 127) can be detected as an overflow in 8-bit signed arithmetic, which is not done unless you specify `-gnato`. The line between range checks and overflow checks has always been fuzzy. GNAT behaves inconsistently (and doesn't conform to the language standard) *unless* you specify `-gnato`.

Comment: Is there a single switch to enable strict following of the standard?

Comment: There are three switches to enable to get GNAT to act like a proper Ada compiler:
-fstack-check -- Stack overflow checking
-gnata        -- Enable assertions (Ada 2012)
-gnato        -- Overflow checking

Comment: AdaCore just [posted](http://www.adacore.com/developers/development-log/NF-73-L620-002-gnat/) on their dev blog that they're changing GNAT's default integer overflow checking behavior: "The default behavior of the compiler is changed so that integer overflow checking (as required by the Ada RM) is now enabled by default. A switch -gnato0 is added which disables integer overflow checking (thus reverting to the previous default behavior)."

Comment: @MarcC: I've added a link to my answer.